# A problem with the output

Tags: programming

i using mathmatica to study lagrange Interpolating,however i couldn't make the output as I want I wrote both who is the output and how i needed

```
 Clear[f, x];
f[x_] = 1 + Cos[3 x]*Exp[-x/2]; a = 0; b = 2;
Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All];    
myone[f_, n_, exactdata_] := 
 Module[{data, data2, i, xi, p1, p2, Lerr},
  data = Table [{xi = a + (b - a)/n i , N[ f[xi], 60]}, {i, 0, n}];

  data2 = Table [{xi = a + (b - a)/n i ,  
     N[Round[10^7  f [xi]]/10^7]}, {i, 0, n} ];
  data = SetAccuracy [data, 300]; 
  data2 = SetAccuracy[data2, 300];

  poly[t_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[data, t];
  polyy[t_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[data2, t];
  eps = 0.5*10^-8;
  maxofy = 2;
      "ERROR\n THEORICAL\n"
       N[(2^(n + 1)*eps*maxofy)/(E*n*Log[n])]
       "PRACTICAL "

       N[FindMaximum[{Abs[poly[t] - polyy[t]], t >= 0 && t <= 2}, t]
]]



myone[f, 10, False]
```

the output is like that

```
    {1.65731*10^-14 "ERROR
       THEORICAL
      " "PRACTICAL ", {3.27205*10^-7 "ERROR
        THEORICAL
       " "PRACTICAL " (t -> 1.80556)}}
```

I need the  output to be

```
ERROR     
1.65731*10^-14  THEORICAL    
3.27205*10^-7   PRACTICAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Column[{"ERROR", Row[{N[(2^(n + 1)*eps*maxofy)/(E*n*Log[n])], " THEORETICAL" }], 
  Row[{ N[FindMaximum[{Abs[poly[t]-polyy[t]], t >= 0 && t <= 2}, t][[1]]], " PRACTICAL"}]}]
```

or

```
Column[{StringForm["ERROR\n `` THEORETICAL\n" , N[(2^(n + 1)*eps*maxofy)/(E*n*Log[n])] ], 
  StringForm["\n `` PRACTICAL", N[FindMaximum[{Abs[poly[t] - polyy[t]], 
     t >= 0 && t <= 2}, t][[1]]]]}]
```

instead of

> "ERROR\n THEORICAL\n"
>   N[(2^(n + 1) eps maxofy)/(E*n*Log[n])]
>   "PRACTICAL "
>   N[FindMaximum[{Abs[poly[t] - polyy[t]], t >= 0 && t <= 2}, t]]